# Xamlspy or snoop tool for Adobe MXML based applications

Tags: air, mxml

I'm new to adobe air applications. In WPF and Silverlight I had a tool that would allow me to see components of a view at runtime similar to developer tools in a browser html site. Is anyone aware of something similar for an adobe air application using mxml for views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly sure if this is what you're looking for, but look into [Monster Debugger](http://demonsterdebugger.com/)

It'll give you a list of all DisplayObjects in your AIR application, as well as traces and other stuff. you can also change values on the fly.

Comment: yeah that's what I was looking for. Of course I couldn't figure out how to make it work with a puremvc flex project but that's another question :) thanks